# GAE always on feature = static VIP?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm wondering if the always on feature would be similar to having a static VIP?  if so then I can directly edit zone file to go that address instead of via the ghs.google.com dns system.  Hopefully this should be better in regards to filtering/censorship etc.

Comment: I don't think so. They will give you three instances that are always on, but it does not have to be the same instances all the time. Good idea to ask this on the GAE forums.

Comment: Re: filtering/censorship. Whereas HTTPS to *.appspot.com has always been blocked in China, regular HTTP also seems to have ceased to work yesterday. :-(

Comment: which GAE forums are there?  The google groups is also censored..  The *.blogspot.com, censored. seems stackoverflow is one of the only uncensored forums left.

Answer (score 0):

No. The always-on feature affects the provision of application instances on the backend; it has no effect on the routing of requests from the frontend to your app.